# Perl Hash of Hashes Issue

Tags: perl, hashtable

I've seen similar questions asked on here ad nauseum but none of those could answer my own question specifically.

I am trying to programatically create a hash of hashes. My problem code is as follows:

```
my %this_hash = ();
if ($user_hash{$uuid})
{
    %this_hash = $user_hash{$uuid};
}

$this_hash{$action} = 1;

$user_hash{$uuid} = %this_hash;
my %test_hash = $user_hash{$uuid};
my $hello_dumper = Dumper \%this_hash;
```

According to my output, $this_hash is being assigned properly but

```
$user_hash{$uuid} = %this_hash
```

is showing a value of 1/8 in the debugger; not sure what his means. I'm also getting a warning: "odd number of elements in hash assignment..."

Comment: Also see http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html for the error message, and http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html for several tutorials on data structures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any time you write

```
%anything = $anything
```

you're doing something wrong. Almost any time you write

```
$anything = %anything
```

you're doing something wrong. That includes when `$anything` is an array or a hash access (i.e. `$array[$index]` or `$hash{$key}`). The values stored in arrays and hashes are always scalars, and arrays and hashes themselves aren't scalars. So, when you want to store a hash in a hash, you store a *reference* to it: `$hash{$key} = \%another_hash`. And when you want to access a hash that's had a reference to it stored in a hash, you dereference: `%another_hash = %{ $hash{$key} }` or `$hashref = $hash{$key}; $value = $hashref->{ $another_key }` or `$value = $hash{$key}{$another_key}`.

For getting up to speed with references I strongly recommend reading the [Perl References Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlreftut) and the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perldsc).

Answer (score 5):

It's not really a "hash of hashes"; it's a "hash of references to hashes".

Try:

```
$user_hash{$uuid} = \%this_hash;
```